# C# ChromeDriver throws exception when executed dynamically by reflection

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to execute test program which uses selenium web driver in custom test runner.

In the test runner, selenium web driver equiped test method is invoked by reflection.

When the test program is run by Visual Studio Test Explorer, it works fine.
Problem occurs when it is run dynamically by reflection.

### The test program is as follows.

```
namespace TrialWebUnitTest
{
    public class WebDriverTest01
    {
        private IWebDriver driver;

        [TestMethod]
        public void NavigateToSeleniumHQByChrome()
        {
            string TargetUrl = "https://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/";
            this.driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Manage().Window.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1000, 800);　// <- driver throws exception here.
            this.driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(TargetUrl);
            this.driver.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

### The custom test runner's core test executing method is as follows.

```
namespace TrialWebUnitTestRunner
{
    public partial class TestForm : Form
    {

        // test button click's event handler.
        private void TestButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string retErrorMsg = string.Empty;
            if (!ExecTestDynamically(ref retErrorMsg))
            {
                // show error information in UI textbox.
                this.this.ResultMessage.Text = retErrorMsg;
            }
        }

        internal bool ExecTestDynamically(ref string retErrorMsg)
        {
            var target = new TrialWebUnitTest.WebDriverTest01();
            System.Type targetType = typeof(TrialWebUnitTest.WebDriverTest01);
            var method = targetType.GetMethod("NavigateToSeleniumHQByChrome");
            try
            {
                method.Invoke(target, null);
                return true
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                retErrorMsg = exp.Message + Environment.NewLine + exp.StackTrance;
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Exception information

> System.InvalidOperationException:
>   disconnected: unable to connect to renderer
>     (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.181)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.31.488763

---

### Sample program

I've written a sample program to reproduce the error.
Please download it from my dropbox url: https://db.tt/HqUTMOKWBl

You can click the link and download 'TrialWebTestForInspection.zip'.
Please extract it in any arbitrary folder and find TrialWebTestForInspection.sln.

The solution consists of two projects, "TrialWebUnitTest" and "TrialWebUnitTestRunner".
The first one is MS Unit Test, and you can run 3 test methods from Visual Studio Test Explorer.

The 3 test methods are very simple. They just launch the browser correspond to the webdriver, and navigate to Selenium HQ site.

The other project is a WindowsForm application which provide a very simple test runner.
It kicks the test methods in previous test project.

When you choose the test method using IE or FireFox driver, it works fine.
On the other hand, when you choose Chrome driver test, it thows exception which I mentioned above.

---

### Things I'd like to know.

First I'd like to know, if it is a bug of current Chrome driver version, or it is a part of specification.

Then I'd like to know, if there is a way to avoid this problem or not.

What I'm afraid of is the possibility that IWebDriver specification originally does not support correct action whent it is run by reflection.

---

### spec of sample program

.NET Framework version 4.6.1

nuget package

- MSTest.TestFramework.1.2.0 MSTest.TestAdapter.1.2.0
  Selenium.WebDriver.3.11.0 Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver.2.37.0
  Selenium.WebDriver.IEDriver.3.11.1 Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver.0.20.0

Chrome Browser version 65.0.3325.181（Official Build）(64 bit)

Comment: The problem was solved. Please refer to this.

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5705

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved. Please refer to this.

The custom TestRunner application didn't refer to the latest chrome-driver version. I had to install selenium.webdrivers not only to the testclass, but also to the testrunner program.

For further information, please refer to the following issue in GitHUB.

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5705